# How to parse param comma separated string ids to has_many mongoid field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, strong-parameters

How to handle `tag_ids` in post params to save it in related model? I would like to use for it only `post_params` method.

```
has_many :tags

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :message, :tag_ids)
end

#Parameters: {"post"=>{"title"=>"asdf", "message"=>"asfd", "tag_ids"=>"543d727a4261729ecd000000,543d8a914261729ecd010000"}}
```

I've got:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue -
Problem:
  Value of type String cannot be written to a field of type Array
```

I found solution but I don't like it, in Post model I've added:

```
def tag_ids=str
  str.split(',').each do |id|
    t = Tag.find(id)
    self.tags << t
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to modify the incoming data in `tag_ids` in `create` action in your controller.

So when you receive the data, before you are saving the data into DB by, for example: `post.create!` you should add parsing to your `PostsController` action `create`:

If you want array of string:

```
post.tag_ids = params[tag_ids]split(",")
```

or if you want array of integers:

```
post.tag_ids = params[tag_ids]split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (I'm assuming you want an array of `ObjectId`)

```
id_array = params['post']['tag_ids'].split(',').map { |id| BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id) }
params['post']['tag_ids'] = id_array
```

Comment: Now I encountered this: `undefined method 'each_pair' for #<Array:0x007fc6f2ebf508>`